# Develop iPhone application remotely?

Tags: xcode, macos, osx-server

4 java developers are new to iPod Touch/iPhone app development.  They have an idea for an app.  They have never used Xcode or Macs before.

Instead of spending money for a new iMac or Mac Mini for each of them, my boss would like to sell them a $999 Apple server, hosted at a facility connected a single T1 line, and have all 4 people work remotely in Xcode.

1. Is this feasible?  Is anyone doing anything like this?  Specifically, is 1 T1 enough for realistic remote app development?
2. Would they have to work in black & white via Logmein or Gotomeeting to get decent speed?
3. Can four people work remotely together on an Xcode project at the same time?
4. Do they absolutely need their own Macs to connect their iPod Touches or iPhones physically to, or can they connect to their existing PCs with iTunes and install their in-development apps that way?

Comment: you're going into lots of troubles :) and btw, I don't really see how you envision running code on the device

Comment: What kind of troubles?  And by "running code on the device", well that's part of what I'm asking - is there a way to copy a compiled  XCode project to a local Windows PC and install it on the iPhone or iPod Touch via iTunes?

Comment: Yes, by installing a provisioning profile in iTunes. However, you won't be able to debug on the device, which is a deal-breaker.

Comment: What about running Apple server in powerful Apple Desktop Mac Pro -computer closeby the workstations? I think I read somewhere it may be possible, http://store.apple.com/us/browse/home/shop_mac/family/mac_pro. If your devs are all connected to the same WIFI, it may be possible, less lag than with Xcode in outside server.

Comment: Related [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13241023/osx-apple-server-for-running-xcode-for-many-developers).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is this feasible? Is anyone doing anything like this? Specifically, is 1 T1 enough for realistic remote app development?

I don't think there is such a things as "realistic remote app development".

> Would they have to work in black & white via Logmein or Gotomeeting to get decent speed?

Does their health care plan cover migraine?

> Can four people work remotely together on an Xcode project at the same time?

You can work with multiple people on one project, but only if each has their own copy of Xcode on their own Mac.

> Do they absolutely need their own Macs to connect their iPod Touches or iPhones physically to, or can they connect to their existing PCs with iTunes and install their in-development apps that way?

You need to have the devices connected to the Mac running Xcode in order to debug. Not debugging on the device is not really an option. You can do some debugging on the iPhone Simulator, but certainly not all.

Answer (score 3):

If you cannot produce a business case for getting a mac mini for each developer I don't think you will make enough money for the business to be worth it - (including paying enough to the programmers)

Comment: You may be right, Mark, but it's not my position to ask whether they are going to make money.  They're having fun, dipping their toes into Mobile Mac development waters, and want the lowest entry cost (for 4 people) possible.  They may be willing to buy a Mac OS X Mini Server to work on the project remotely.




Is there a problem running Mac OS X Server, with XCode and Subversion for version control, remotely?  Can you or anyone give examples of what the problems might be?

Comment: @ANE what about buying the Mac -server and some Mac -laptops/desktops and pair them together? If you are new to mac, you may not even know whether you want to have iMacs, Macbook Airs or Macbook Pros. Me after breaking laptops with active ventilation is tilted towards passive-ventilated devices such Air/iPad/etc but workplace when needing a lot of power with the most powerful device there -- and btw iPad is not for development (Xcode not running there). I would test all devices and make people change them between one-another -- or better co-operate over them -- before larger investments.

Answer (score 2):

The lowest entry cost is a Mac Mini for each developer, plus the cost of at least one iPod Touch/iPhone plus the $99 per year that Apple charges to load software onto the device.

What your boss is proposing is simply not feasible and quite unrealistic. It's also frankly insulting to the developers.

If cost is that much of an issue, buy second-hand or refurbished.

Comment: Your lowest entry cost answer is helpful.  As for the rest: The original idea for a remote controlled development server actually came from the lead Java developer.  My boss just said we could host it for him if it were feasible.  (which it isn't)  The other developers are part of his team, and are already getting paid.  So in the future, it may be wise for you to not jump to conclusions about whether it is "insulting" or not.  Thanks for answering though.

Comment: Do I need to pay $99 before submitting anything to the market even though I developed only for me?

Comment: Yes. You must purchase a license for any kind of development.

Answer (score 0):

Check http://macminicolo.net/dayone for remote development using jenkins etc. in a Mac mini hosting infrastructure.